# How to call REST with POST in Apache camel?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I want to call a REST API with Apache Camel.

When I do it from Postman I use the following:

```
Method: Post
Headers: 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body
Check x-www-form-urlencoded option

3 Key value parameters added
Username: ABC
Password: ABC
Country: UK
```

After setting up this configuration I am able to consume my REST API and it responds with an XML.

But I really don't know how to write this on Camel.

Comment: Why not start with reviewing the documentation: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/README.md Questions here should be for more specific issues such as how to handle a certain error or if you can't get the code to compile, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the @marcin-pietraszek precise answer and based on your last comment:

> how can I add Body (Username: ABC, Password: ABC, Country: UK) parameters inside your code have shared

Depends on the services' interface. If it's query parameters, you could use:

```
from("direct:start").
    setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")).
    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).
    setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("Username=ABC&Password=ABC&Country=UK"))
    to("http://www.google.com");
```

If it's directly in the body you could use:

```
from("direct:start").
    setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")).
    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).
    setBody(constant("Username: ABC, Password: ABC, Country: UK"))
    to("http://www.google.com");
```

Remind that you should look into the service you are posting how it expect to receive the body (JSON, XML, CSV, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) provides an example:

```
from("direct:start").
    setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")).
    setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).
    to("http://www.google.com");
```

I assume that you could also use `setBody` method there ;).

Comment: Thanks...!! May I know how can I add Header(Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and Body (Username: ABC, Password: ABC, Country: UK) parameters inside your code have shared ?